# Refreshing safariViewController causes OAuth2 to fail

Tags: ios, swift, safari, oauth-2.0

I made a similar question about the library in question (Keycloak), but I feel it may actually be related to code outside the library.

I am trying to use a Safari View Controller with Aerogear OAuth2 in order to login via Google.

However, when trying to log in, if you try to refresh in the middle of the login process, I am getting an error from Keycloak - which is an access management service of, "No access token".

```
let keycloakHost = ServerConfigurator.sharedInstance.keycloakUrl

config = KeycloakConfig(
    clientId: "company-name",
    host: keycloakHost,
    realm: "master",
    isOpenIDConnect: true)

config.webView = .safariViewController

config.webViewHandler = self.webViewHandler
oauthModule = KeycloakOAuth2Module(config: config, session: KeycloakClient.session)
```

I am having trouble finding why a Safari View Controller refresh would cause an error like that.

Could it be related to a new session? As it is happening only on refresh and only in the Safari View Controller, part of me feels like there is some misconfiguration I am making with the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had a similar problem, but i resolved with the keycloak client

in my Realm - client - Yourclient - Settings search Access Type and put public

Try again and you could login successful

Comment: How would I set this in the configuration?

Comment: In your keycloak client, this is the route:                                              Realm - client - Yourclient - Settings search Access Type and put public